# Invalid base64: "{"instances": [{"in0":[863],"in1":[882]}]}" when testing Amazon SageMaker model endpoint using the AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to Amazon SageMaker and I am closely following this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/ to create a machine learning-powered REST API with Amazon API Gateway mapping templates and Amazon SageMaker

when I run the following command on terminal (**Step 2 of the Tutorial** )

```
aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint \
  --endpoint-name <endpoint-name> \
  --body '{"instances": [{"in0":[863],"in1":[882]}]}' \
  --content-type application/json \
  --accept application/json \
  results
```

I get the following **Error:** `Invalid base64: "{"instances": [{"in0":[863],"in1":[882]}]}"`
My endpoint is `InService` on the SageMaker console and the example Jupyter notebook run successfully. (I also substituted `<endpoint-name>` with the actual name - same error received with/without quotations around the name)

Using **zsh** here is the aws cli version:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.15 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/19.4.0 botocore/2.0.0dev19
```

Wondering what the problem could be. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the body contents is being expected to be base 64 encoded, try base64 encoding the body before passing it to the invoke statement.

Comment: Hmm, so the response should have a body attribute: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html?highlight=invoke#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint. Body is a streaming body so can it be piped to a file to see the full result?

Answer (score 12):

Try adding `--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out` param.

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the aws-cli version. your command is compatible with V1. need to specify `--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out` for V2.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/clarify-processing-job-data-format-tabular-precheck.html